# How to set up the *NIX terminal to function similar to an IDE?

Tags: linux, terminal, vim, shell, tmux

I would like to set up something in a shell to give me an IDE-like experience using only the shell (no X). The closest I have come is using tmux,  with vim in one pane and the command line in the other. That way from vim I can `.w !bash` to run a line.

But this is not satisfactory to me because the environment does not persist between commands run seperately.

If I run:

`var1=FOO`

and then

`echo $var1`

each using `.w !bash`, `FOO` will not be echoed.

What I really want to do is go through a text file in one pane, and use a shortcut to send a line to the terminal in the other pane, as part of that terminal session. What is the right combination of tools to achieve this? I understand emacs can be configured to do something like this with its own terminal emulator, but I would like a solution that works with the stock tools (such as on an installer).

Edit: tmux select-copy-paste isn't so bad but still a little awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prototype solution with `sh`, `vim` and `tmux`, quick and dirty proof of concept.

Your `.w !bash` runs `bash` and sends the current line to its stdin. Let's replace `bash` with a script that injects a line from its stdin into a different pane in `tmux`.

This is the basic script:

```
#!/bin/sh
pane="$(tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_active} #D' | awk '$1==0 {print $2;exit}')"
IFS= read -r line
tmux send-keys -l -t "$pane" "$line"
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" 'C-j'
```

The procedure, short explanation:

1. Identify a pane that is not active.
2. Read a line from stdin.
3. Send the line to the pane as if it was typed.
4. Send <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the pane.

Save it as `trun`, make it executable and reachable via `$PATH`. Now if you have two panes in `tmux` and run `trun` in one of them, and type a line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the line will be injected into the other pane.

In `vim` instead of `.w !bash` invoke `.w !trun`, it should work. Bind this to a key for easy access.

Notes:

- The script doesn't check if there are exactly two panes.
- The script doesn't care what runs in the target pane; it just sends keys.

Comment: Yes, that works like a charm, thank you!